# No result or error when using `gitbook pdf`

Tags: macos, pdf, gitbook

I'm using a mca and my system is 
**macOS Mojave 10.14.2** version, gitbook version is 
**CLI version: 2.3.2
GitBook version: 3.2.3**
I want to generate a pdf using the command `gitbook pdf`, but nothing happens, picture as follow
[image]

`git server` is ok, I don't know why. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

you should put down your calibre-ebook version from 4.X to 3.x

https://download.calibre-ebook.com/3.48.0/

Comment: This answer could be really good if you explained why this would solve the problem.